# #1109 - Unknown table 'ConcertDetails' in field list

Tags: mysql, triggers

I was attempting to run a simple Insert into my CustomerOrders table and got the error: *#1109 - Unknown table 'ConcertDetails' in field list*

I did some searches on this and looked at about 7 different stack overflow posts on it but still not sure what is wrong. I also looked up information on triggers and there seems to be different syntax on different sites. The weird thing is this trigger used to work just fine, not sure what has been altered since 4 days ago.

I tried changing some things, for instance I removed my trigger and it let me insert, but when I put the trigger back I couldn't insert any more, so there must be something wrong with the trigger. This is what I have for the trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `alterPurchasePrice`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `alterPurchasePrice` BEFORE INSERT ON `CustomerOrders`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF new.DiscountCode = 'yes' THEN
        SET new.PurchasePrice = ConcertDetails.Cost - 10;
    END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

The purpose of the trigger is to lower the price by $10 if the user types 'yes' into the DiscountCode field.

This involves the tables:

- **CustomerOrders**: ConcertID, CustomerName, Discount Code, OrderID,
- **PurchasePrice** ConcertDetails: ConcertDate, ConcertID, Cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a SELECT to retrieve values from other tables.

To get the value of "cost" from "ConcertDetails" table, for a specific concert, we could write a query like this:

```
 SELECT ConcertDetails.cost  
   FROM ConcertDetails 
  WHERE ConcertDetails.concertid = ?
```

assuming that "concertid" is the primary key (or unique key) of the ConcertDetails table, we would be guaranteed that the query would return at most one row.

To put that to use in the trigger, we should be able to do something like this

```
SET NEW.PurchasePrice 
  = ( SELECT d.cost - 10 AS discount_price
        FROM ConcertDetails d
       WHERE d.concertid = NEW.concertid
    );
```

The value of the `concertid` column of the row to be inserted from the CustomerOrders table will be supplied for the query through the reference to `NEW.concertid`. The return from that query will be assigned to the purchaseprice column.

If the query returns more than one row (which could happen if we don't have any kind of guarantee that "concertid" is unique in the "ConcertDetails" table), the trigger will throw a "too many rows" error.

If there are no rows returned, we'd expect a NULL value to be assigned would be assigned to "purchaseprice". We would also get a NULL returned if the "cost" column is set to NULL.

Is there some sort of guarantee that "cost" will never be less than 10? If the returned Cost is 6, then the value assigned to "purchaseprice" would be -4. If we want the value assigned to "purchaseprice" to never be less than zero, we could do something like this:

```
SET NEW.purchaseprice
  = ( SELECT GREATEST(d.cost-10,0) AS discount_price
        FROM ConcertDetails d
       WHERE d.concertid = NEW.concertid
    );
```

---

Other notes:

I'd recommend a different naming convention for your triggers. With multiple tables and multiple triggers, it can get kind of confusing, when looking for triggers on CustomerOrders table, to remember that the name of the BEFORE INSERT trigger is "alterPurchasePrice". Especially if you (or someone else) is coming back to work on the system six months or six years from now.

The convention we follow for trigger names is to use the name of the table, followed by an underscore, followed by one of:  bi, bu, bd, ai, au, ad (for Before/After Insert/Update/Delete). (Since MySQL doesn't allow more than one trigger for each of those, we don't get naming collisions. And it makes it easier to check whether a BEFORE INSERT trigger exists on a table, before someone writes a BEFORE INSERT trigger that does something else.)

I also mention, in regards to the use of CamelCase table names... the MySQL Reference Manual says this:

> To avoid problems ... it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and tables using **lowercase** names. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Then again, these are just conventions. We also follow a convention to name tables by naming what a *single* row represents. If we had a requirement to create this table, we would assign the name `customer_order`. And the BEFORE INSERT trigger on the table would be named `customer_order_bi`

Comment: Should there be anything before SET NEW.PurchasePrice? I  am getting : #1193 - Unknown system variable 'PurchasePrice' . I ran the query on the CustomerOrders table in PhpMyAdmin

Comment: We should be able to drop that SET statement in, in place of the existing SET statement. Just replace that one line in the trigger. (This assumes that there is a column named "PurchasePrice" in the "CustomerOrders" table.)